# Verify who is doing the update and only allow the field to be updated by someone with "supervisor level" access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying different levels of users to have different accesses to different form fields. Some users can fill in fields on the form, others can update others can delete to comply with the principle of segregation of duties. In this field I'm trying to make it so that all users can fill it in, however, once filled in, only supervisor users can update or delete it.

This is what I did, it gets unable to update once filled, however, not reopen when a “supervisor level ''''user” try to update.

```
Private Sub DateStarted_Click()
If Not IsNull(DateStarted) Then

   Me.DateStarted.Locked = True
   
   If DLookup("TFSupervisor", "qrySplashUserCheck") = True Then
        Me.DateStarted.Locked = False
    

Else

Me.DateStarted.Locked = False

End If

   
End Sub
```

Comment: What if you filled a hidden text box with an abbreviation for a user level on form load?  C for Common, S for Supervisor, M for Manager, etc...  Then you just check the text box for a value to determine if the field is editable?  In theory, once a person pulls up the form their user level will never change, so you don't have to worry about that, and you don't have to keep querying the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The `DLookup` will return the first value it finds in the `qrySplashUserCheck` query under the `TFSupervisor` field. If nothing is found, it will return Null.

Therefore the statement below is incorrect.

```
If DLookup("TFSupervisor", "qrySplashUserCheck") = True Then
```

What you probably trying to do is:

```
If Nz(DLookup("TFSupervisor", "qrySplashUserCheck"), vbNullstring) = "User" Then
```

---

(Edit after comments).

Scrap the `DLookup` and try with `DCount`.

```
DCount("*", "qrySplashUserCheck", "TFSupervisor = True")
```

To avoid making the DCount() call each time, handle it conditionally (as per your example).

```
With DateStarted
    If IsNull(.Value) Then 
        .Locked = False
    Else
        .Locked = DCount("*", "qrySplashUserCheck", "TFSupervisor = True") = 0
    End If
End With
```

Comment: still doing the same, blocking everyone to update.

Comment: Then the DLookup is wrong. Can you describe the structure of the `qrySplashUserCheck` query? What should the lookup return and how when you specify no criteria?

Comment: this query checks the network user authorizations in a table called usersecurity

Comment: SELECT tblUserSecurity.NetworkUsername, tblUserSecurity.FirstName, tblUserSecurity.LastName, tblUserSecurity.EmailAddress, tblUserSecurity.EnableAccess, tblUserSecurity.tabCT, tblUserSecurity.tabCM, tblUserSecurity.CMPlanActivity, tblUserSecurity.tabTE, tblUserSecurity.TEEndorsementRpts, tblUserSecurity.tabTF, tblUserSecurity.tabDS, tblUserSecurity.tabYR, tblUserSecurity.tabSR, tblUserSecurity.tabAIY, tblUserSecurity.tabCerts, tblUserSecurity.CertsPrint, tblUserSecurity.tabPrices, tblUserSecurity.PREdit, tblUserSecurity.tabUS,

Comment: tblUserSecurity.tabStats, tblUserSecurity.tabCO, tblUserSecurity.tabPS, tblUserSecurity.tabCR, tblUserSecurity.TFSupervisor, tblUserSecurity.CertsEdit, tblUserSecurity.CREdit, tblUserSecurity.tabND, tblUserSecurity.NDEdit, tblUserSecurity.tabHY, tblUserSecurity.DSEdit
FROM tblUserSecurity
WHERE (((tblUserSecurity.NetworkUsername)=GetCurrentUsername()));

Comment: So the query will contain max 1 record, that of the current logged user if exists or nothing. Correct?

Comment: @KostasK. - I'm rusty on Access, might this be better on a "Form Dirty" event?

Comment: @Johnny Bones I believe it should be handled at individual control level. The dirty applies to the whole form and is only available when the form is dirty, but what if no changes made? I would handle it the `Enter` event - that's when the control gets the focus.

Comment: correct, its the connect user and what boxes are checked with what his/her is allowed to do

Comment: my intend was once user input something, the access will check query if user have tfsupervisor checked, if so, he can update, if not, unable to update, else (field empty) everyone can fill it

Comment: still doing the same, once filled no one can update the form field

Comment: Then check what the query returns. To be able to edit, the expression `DCount("*", "qrySplashUserCheck", "TFSupervisor = True") = 0` should evaluate to False. Evaluating True means either the query has no records or the `TFSupervisor` field for the logged user is false.

Comment: Kostas, there is an insight, I'll review the query and let you guys know